# Count number of unique character sets in contiguous sub-strings of a string

Tags: python

I was solving a programming question the other day. The question is to find the number of distinct character sets in each substring of a string. For example:

For the string `"abbc"` , all the substrings are `a,ab,abb,abbc,b,bb,bbc,bc,c`. And unique character sets for each substring are `{a},{a,b},{a,b},{a,c,b},{b},{b},{c,b},{b,c},{c}`. So the number of distinct character sets is 6 i.e, [{a},{a,b},{a,b,c},{b,c},{b},{c}].

I tried  the solution using `frozenset()` and `dictionary` in python as follows:

```
from collections import Counter

arr =['wpcbgphrbqspegjo','qejyogmmtlmgqzi','wroyjvcaiallyshhspfy','qvjiayljivsei','auxpaufisazsdpcpkzz','qdyvxihsmwwyit','ejmmxvrkxb','rapbkfkvgyka','hrklzzudfh','hhmzxkpdgehxjgrmgjex']

out1 = {}
for a in arr:
    out = {}
    lent = len(a)
    for i in range(lent):
        for j in range(i,lent):
            #print(s[i:j+1])
            temp = frozenset(a[i:j+1])
            out[temp] = out.get(temp,0)+1

    print(len(out.keys()))
```

However, my output and expected outputs are different as follows:

My output: `[81, 75, 83, 56, 68, 77, 39, 54, 43, 81]`
Expected output: `[93,75,113,55,83,76,38,53,42,101]`

I can't figure what went wrong. Also is there any way to optimize the code

Comment: what is 's' is the len(s)?

Comment: Besides that `s` is not defined, I test your code and it gave the expected output plus one for each value, so I replaced the last line with `print(len(out.keys())-1)` and everything went fine. Roughly; I set `lent` to 100.

Comment: I messed up in that part. I edited the code and it works fine and gives the expected answer now.

Comment: Any idea on the optimization? My code is just brute force. One case I figured out is if length of string is `n` and consists of `n`, then the answer would be `n*(n+1)/2`